# Show that the expected number of steps from $x$ to $y$ is finite

Tags: probability, markov-chains

> Let an irreducible Markov Chain with $n$ states. Show that the expected number of steps from $x$ to $y$ is finite.

So I already found the relation (basing on [this article](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~siva/410/lec8ann.pdf))

$$n_{ij} = \sum_{k\ne j} P_{ik} n_{kj}$$

where $n_{ij}$ is the expected number of steps from $i$ to $j$, but that's a *recursive relation*.

Can I somehow utilize this relation to prove the expected time is indeed finite?

Comment: Do you mean the expected number of transitions from state $x$ to state $y$, or the expected number of transitions, conditioned on starting in state $x$, to reach state $y$?

Comment: the later. i.e. given a starting point $x$,what's the expected number of steps reaching $y$?